# Why is asyncio.sleep() preventing my websocket server from receiving input?

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, sleep, python-asyncio

I am trying to build a library which allows for python control over a dom within a slave browser application.

I am currently trying not to send information TO the dom, but request and then receive a piece of information from it.

This example below is configured to requisition an attribute (id in this case) about a given element.

The setup is rather simple. Send request, check repeatedly for that request's id to be registered as a non-None value within a registry, using asyncio.sleep to halt the checking procedure and release control back to the receiver so it can, well, receive.

This, by the way, is a near identical copy of a (supposedly) working implementation. Search Python Sofi Gui in google if you're curious.

asyncio.sleep seems to be halting the entire process, not returning control to the webserver for the receiving of signals. Is there a problem with my understanding, my implementation, or both?

python

```
import os, sys, asyncio, websockets, json, time

websocket_global = None
requests = {}

event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def quit():

    os.system( 'kill $(lsof -t -i :9000)' )

async def load( websocket ):

    await get_attribute( websocket, 'head', 'id' )

async def receive( websocket, path ):

    try: 
        async for input in websocket: await handle_input( websocket, input )

    except Exception as e: os.system( 'kill $(lsof -t -i :9000)' )

async def handle_input( websocket, input ):

    message = json.loads( input )

    if message[ 'message' ] == 'quit': quit()

    if message[ 'message' ] == 'load': await load( websocket )

    if message[ 'message' ] == 'response': receive_response( message )

def transmit( websocket, message ):

    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe( websocket.send( message ), event_loop )

def receive_response( message ):

    responses[ message[ 'message_id' ] ] = message[ 'value' ]

async def wait_for_response( request_id ):

    while requests[ request_id ] == None: await asyncio.sleep( .01 )

    print( requests[ request_id ] ) ###<------------- The above asyncio.sleep is blocking the rest of the progrem
                                ###preventing the receive function from firing. Isn't sleep supposed to
                                ###let the program continue?

 async def get_attribute( websocket, selector, attr ):

    request_id = time.time(); requests[ request_id ] = None

    transmit( websocket, json.dumps( { 'message': 'get_attribute', 'request_id': request_id, 'selector': selector, 'attr': attr } ) )

    response = await wait_for_response( request_id )

    return response

quit()

html_path = os.path.dirname( os.path.realpath( __file__ ) )
html_path = html_path.replace( ' ', '\ ' )
html_path = html_path + '/main.html'

os.system( 'open -a Safari ' + html_path )

start_server = websockets.serve( receive, '0.0.0.0', 9000 )
event_loop.run_until_complete( start_server )
event_loop.run_forever()
```

javascript

var socket = null;

```
function get_attribute( message ) {

    var response = {};
    var target_element = document.getElementById( message[ 'selector' ] );

    if ( target_element == null ) {
        response = { 'message': 'response', 'request_id': message[ 'request_id' ], 'response': 'Element not Found' };
    }

    if ( target_element != null && target_element.getAttribute( message[ 'attr' ] ) == null ) {
        response = { 'message': 'response', 'request_id': message[ 'request_id' ], 'response': 'Attribute not Found' };
    }

    if ( target_element != null && target_element.getAttribute( message[ 'attr' ] ) != null ) {
        var target_attribute = target_element.getAttribute( message[ 'attr' ] )
        response = { 'message': 'response', 'request_id': message[ 'request_id' ], 'response': target_attribute };
    }

    socket.send( JSON.stringify( response ) );

}

function handle_input( message ) {

    if ( message[ 'message' ] == 'get_attribute' ) { get_attribute( message ) }

}

window.onload = function(event) {

    socket = new WebSocket( 'ws://0.0.0.0:9000' );

    socket.onopen = function( event ) {
        socket.send( JSON.stringify( { 'message': 'load' } ) )
        setInterval( function () { socket.send( JSON.stringify( { 'message': 'tick' } ) ) }, 1000 )
    }

    socket.onmessage = function( event ) {
        handle_input( JSON.parse( event.data ) )
    }

}

window.onbeforeunload = function( event ) {
    socket.send( JSON.stringify( { 'message': 'quit' } ) )
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="head">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="handler.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="body">

</body>
</html>
```

Apologies for poor spelling or syntax errors. My keyboard is starting to go and various keys having become uncooperative.

Answer (score 0):

nothing is setting `requests[request_id]` so the while loop will never exit.  Also you should avoid global variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
if message[ 'message' ] == 'response': receive_response( message )
```

and

```
def receive_response( message ):

    responses[ message[ 'message_id' ] ] = message[ 'value' ]
```

Solved it though.

Within the while loop in `receive_response` I placed:

```
message = await pyscript.websocket.recv();

handle_response( json.loads( message ) );
```

and created the function:

```
def handle_response( input ):

    if input[ 'message' ] == 'response': receive_response( input );
```

I have no formal education though so I ask, why do you frown upon globals? They have always served me well enough.

Comment: Please refer to [this page](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad) for some of the arguments against globals.